# How to make a graph out of a reactive table with 2 inputs? R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I'm building a little web app that is keep track of claims by an organization or project on a monthly basis. I have my data frame in a "long" format and have been able to get some values but I am having a really hard time building a simple bargraph that shows the number the count by month.

My goal is to have the table update based on the inputs. So if 1 organization is selected only the values of that organization appear in the graph.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

`````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
          flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
            orientation: columns
            vertical_layout: fill
            graphics: yes
            runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
        library(flexdashboard)
        library(ggplot2)
        library(plotly)
        library(DT)
        library(htmltools)
        library(readr)
        library(shiny)
        library(knitr)



monthly_claims <- data.frame(OrgName = c("Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha", 
                                         "Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta",
                                         "Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta"),
                             Claimed_By_Project = c("Alpha 1","Alpha 1","Alpha 2","Alpha 2","Alpha 2","Alpha 3","Alpha 3","Alpha 3",
                                                    "Beta 1","Beta 1","Beta 1","Beta 1","Beta 2","Beta 2","Beta 2","Beta 2","Beta 2",
                                                    "Delta 1","Delta 1","Delta 1","Delta 1","Delta 2","Delta 2","Delta 2","Delta 2"),
                             Month_Claimed = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,
                                               1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
                                               1,1,1,1,2,2,3

                             ))

```

Inputs {.sidebar data-width=300}
=====================================



```{r}
selectInput("input_type","Select Organization: ", c("All", monthly_claims$OrgName))
selectInput("input_type2", "Select Project: ", c("All", monthly_claims$Claimed_By_Project))


claims <- reactive({
  mc <- monthly_claims
  if(input$input_type !="All")
    mc <- subset(mc, OrgName == input$input_type)
  if(input$input_type2 !="All")
    mc <- subset(mc, Claimed_By_Project == input$input_type2)
  mc
})



```

# Page 1 


### Bar Graph by Month??

```{r}

data <- as.data.frame(table(monthly_claims$Month_Claimed))

ggplot(data, aes(Var1, Freq)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")


````
`````

DATA

```
monthly_claims <- data.frame(OrgName = c("Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Alpha", 
                                         "Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta",
                                         "Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta","Delta"),
                             Claimed_By_Project = c("Alpha 1","Alpha 1","Alpha 2","Alpha 2","Alpha 2","Alpha 3","Alpha 3","Alpha 3",
                                                    "Beta 1","Beta 1","Beta 1","Beta 1","Beta 2","Beta 2","Beta 2","Beta 2","Beta 2",
                                                    "Delta 1","Delta 1","Delta 1","Delta 1","Delta 2","Delta 2","Delta 2","Delta 2"),
                             Month_Claimed = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,
                                               1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
                                               1,1,1,1,2,2,3

                             ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your bar chart have a reactive dependency on `claims`. E.g.,

```
ggplot(claims(), aes(x = Month_Claimed)) + 
    geom_bar()
```

This is beginner Shiny, I think you would get some value from following some of the intro Shiny courses [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/).

For example, you'll also need `plotOutput` and `renderPlot`. Full minimal example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("input_type",
        "Select Organization: ",
        choices = c("All", monthly_claims$OrgName)
    ),
    selectInput("input_type2",
        "Select Project: ",
        choices = c("All", monthly_claims$Claimed_By_Project)
    ),
    plotOutput("plt")    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    claims <- reactive({
        mc <- mutate(monthly_claims, Month_Claimed = factor(Month_Claimed)
        if(input$input_type !="All")
            mc <- subset(mc, OrgName == input$input_type)
        if(input$input_type2 !="All")
            mc <- subset(mc, Claimed_By_Project == input$input_type2)
        mc
    })
    
    output$plt <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(claims(), aes(x = Month_Claimed)) + 
            geom_bar()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You're going to have issues with getting combinations of the two filter variables that don't exist, so you might want to look into having the second `selectInput` choices depend on the first. That's another question though, and there are plenty of examples out there for that type of thing.